# Do Process while Progress Bar is Running

Tags: vb.net

I know that knowledge is expensive, but is there who want to help me
i want to run process when progress bar is running,
i try with this code

```
Public Class Form2
Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
Call Prcss()  
End Sub
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If Progress.Value < 100 Then
        Progress.Value += 2
    ElseIf Progress.Value = 100 Then
        Timer1.Stop()
        Form1.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub Prcss()
    With Progress
        .Value = 0
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(450)
        Label1.Text = "Renewing Custom Content"
        .Value = 20
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(450)
        Label1.Text = "Getting Information"
        .Value = 50
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(450)
        Label1.Text = "Downloading Udpdate"
        .Value = 70
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(450)
        Label1.Text = "Ready to Start"
        .Value = 100
    End With
End Sub
```

i don't know where is my mistake, i read this on my book.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) or a [Thread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    For i As Integer = 1 To 1000
        BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(CInt(i / 10))
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
    ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    MessageBox.Show("Finished!")
End Sub
```

This is the basic example and require you to add a BackgroundWorker to the form. You can see help here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx